# Pull to refresh Webview in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pull-to-refresh

**Edit:** CustomWebView is a class that inherits WebView; pageWebView is an instance of CustomWebView, so **pageWebView is a WebView instance.**

I realize that there are some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I don't see accepted/ working solutions, so here I am.

I'm working on 'Pull to refresh' feature, when users pull the page, the app will refresh it (WebviewPage.xaml).
I've done my research and get this working so far: (animation shows and method RefreshView_Refreshing() was hit)

**WebviewPage.xaml.cs**

```
void RefreshView_Refreshing(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        //to do: pull to refresh
        //code: reload WebviewPage here
        myRefreshView.IsRefreshing = false;// refresh animation end
    }
```

The part that need to be refreshed on **WebviewPage.xaml**:

```
<RefreshView Refreshing="RefreshView_Refreshing"
         x:Name="myRefreshView" IsEnabled="False">
    <ScrollView
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ctrl:CustomWebView x:Name="pageWebView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsWorking, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}"/>
            <ContentView x:Name="isWorkingView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsWorking}">
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsWorking}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></ActivityIndicator>
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>
```

So the question is, how do I implement the code of **reloading/refreshing the view** inside RefreshView? Can anyone please help me out? TIA!

Comment: on a standard XF `WebView` you would call its `Reload` method.  I have no idea what `CustomWebView` is or if it supports that

Comment: @Jason `CustomWebView` is a class that inherits WebView. So yes, I can call `pageWebView.reload()` but it doesn't reload.

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming that you are using Xamarin.Forms Webview. In order to refresh it while pulling the refreshview you have to do this inside your `RefreshView_Refreshing` like this

```
void RefreshView_Refreshing(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
       
        myRefreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
        pageWebView.Reload();

    }
```

Comment: Hi Anand, I added `pageWebView.Reload();` but the page still doesn't reload. I also tried adding `pageWebView.Source = URL;` does not works either. Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you put reload line inside Device.BeginInvokeonMainthread?